# Keep temperature at exact 62C/143F for an hour

Tags: temperature

Is there an appliance with which I can keep something at a specific temperature, in this case 62C, without constantly checking manually? I have been looking at thermostat controlled induction plates but haven't found any that go that low.

Edit for more information:

- the temparature should stay within 2 or 3 degrees of the target, it's less of a problem if it goes too low, but too high chemically alters some key ingredients.
- it should be able to do at least about 500ml of volume.

Comment: sous-vide stuff?

Comment: The answer is obviously yes, but it depends on what, and how much, you're trying to keep at 62 C and how closely you need the temperature controlled. How much you're willing to spend is another important consideration. // We need more information to give any sort of helpful answer.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  An immersion circulator (or sous vide stick, as the tool has become popularly known) can maintain water at a very precise temperature, almost indefinitely.  If you identify your application, we can be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are we talking liquid or solids? Water has a high specific heat, meaning you need a lot of energy to change their temperature. That being said, I'd either go for a sous-vide approach, seal whatever you want to keep at that temperature in bags and toss it into a pre-warmed 62° C water bath, or buy/rent a medium/upper quality range dehydrator. These usually work for temperatures between 50-90° C, and are quite accurate.